# Shift/reduce conflict in yacc grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, yacc, lalr

I've written a grammar that as rules as follows:

```
A : B '?'  
  | B
  | A '+' A
  ;

B : "a"
  | "c" A "t" A
  ;
```

And this gives me a shift/reduce conflict on

```
A : B . '?'  (96)
A : B .  (98)
```

I've tried multiple ways to change the grammar but I seem to create even more conflicts when I try to change things. How can I remove this conflict?

Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How would you expect the parser to parse `cata?`?  Which A gets the trailing `?`?

Comment: The "c" and the other chars are meant to represent tokens, sorry I wasnt clear on that

Comment: That doesn't answer my question: you can get to cata? by starting with A->B? or A->B, meaning the grammar is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: Oh I understand it now, I cant really do anything about it the grammar itself is ambigous. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LALR(1) parsers resolve their conflicts using a single-character lookahead. When the lookahead can't disambiguate between the different actions, the conflict is then shown to the user.

In the following state, a "?" lookahead means the parser can shift.

```
A : B . '?'
A : B .
```

But what if it reduces A? It could possible reduce into the following state:

```
B: "c" A "t" A .
```

Which, by reducing B, could lead right back into:

```
A : B . '?'
A : B .
```

Therefore, "?" is also a valid lookahead to reduce.

So how can you solve this?

You have two options:

1) Try to rewrite the grammar with left-recursion instead of right-recursion. It *might* help, but that's not guaranteed.

2) Tell YACC which one to choose whenever it has this conflict (For example, using %left or %right).

Or, perhaps, use a smarter parser. For example [elkhound](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/) or antlr.

Comment: A single *token* lookahead.